Python - Extract data from text
I have lots of files in a database and with a command I can retrieve information from a file, but the problem is that I get this very abstract result, for example
[File({'added_on': 1720455648, 'amount_left': 0, 'size': 1460305985, 'content_path': 'A:\Very Very Important Folder', 'name': 'Important File1.pdf', 'format': 'pdf'})]

I've searched the internet for all kinds of solutions but haven't found anything...
What I'd like to do is just separate the data and make, for example, a name variable that is equal to its associated data (in this case "Important File1.pdf").
And at the same time do the same thing with the other variables
I don't know if my request is very clear
It may seem very simple, but I'm a Python beginner, so I don't know much about it.
Sorry, and thanks in advance
I did a lot of googling but nothing was really explicit to help me.
I also tried to help myself via the add-on I use but it's not very advanced.

Is the File prefix always present? And does the command return a list of File objects, like [File(...), File(...)]. FWIW, the content inside of File() looks like plain old JSON, or at least a dictionary.

result[0].name will probably return what you want.

Do you get this exact result as a string?

@JRiggles It's a list of file but with a tag "id" I have sorted the results

@Barmar How i use that ? i write 'print(result[4].name)'

@ThierryLathuille No, I used random data for the example, but yes, it's almost the same tags that are given to me.

You can print it, you can assign it to a variable, you can pass it as an argument to another function, etc.

@Barmar I tried to use the formula but it didn't work, it returned " ' " after several tries I deduced that the number I put here [5] gave me the letter that corresponded to it, for example for the word orange with [3] the program returned "n". There must be another way

It sounds like you've got a string, the result of str(list_of_files)

how do you get these data? Do you get list of objects File or string? What is File? We can't see your code, we can't see your computer and we can't read in your mind - so we can't help you. You have to show all details in question (not in comments)

If you don’t have to read the ‘File’ on the line, you can do:
import pandas as pd

def File(dummy):
    # Dummy function to extract the dictionary
    return dummy

st = [File({'added_on': 1720455648, 'amount_left': 0, 'size': 1460305985, 'content_path': 'A:\Very Very Important Folder', 'name': 'Important File1.pdf', 'format': 'pdf'})]
# print(type(st))

df = pd.DataFrame(st[0], index=['i',])
df['added_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['added_on'], unit='s')

print(df.to_string())

Output:
             added_on  amount_left        size                   content_path                 name format
i 2024-07-08 16:20:48            0  1460305985  A:\Very Very Important Folder  Important File1.pdf    pdf

Note: Not clear what data this is and how you produce it. You tagged you question as sqlite. See also comment from @furas above. Is this a database dump?
